# php Api hosted on AWS s3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I wanna host a php file that retrieve data from a mysql DB how ever aws is not authorizing POST method. 
I need to know how can I add the code in PHP knowing I already configured the Bucket policy and CORS

Comment: What's the exact problem here? Hosting any PHP file is not related to the ability to accept POST requests, and CORS is once more something completely different

Comment: so what would be the solution then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try Amazon API Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

You can only serve static content from an S3 - PHP will not be processed.

If you want to set up a dynamic PHP website on AWS have a look at [LightSail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/) and its LAMP stack.